# Can a dashed shadow pattern be created using view.layer.shadowPath?

Tags: ios, swift

[image: Shadow Pattern]

I'd imagine a custom UIBezierPath could be created to produce this dashed shadow pattern.

Note that the shadow is visible on all sides but the left and right sides have that dashed pattern.

I've seen this implementation for creating a custom UIBezierPath for a shadow but am unsure of the points to set.

```
let path = UIBezierPath()
path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: xValue, y: yValue))
view.layer.shadowPath = path.cgPath
```

Comment: Is this for iOS? macOS? other? Please fix tags.

Comment: @ryantxr Just did

Comment: You can create three paths, each spanning the whole width of the red rectangle, and leave some gaps on the vertical axis?

Comment: @CodeDifferent I can give that a shot.